# Null pointer exception when retrieving Parcelable Object 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' even though said object exists inside Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, object

Hi my app suddenly returns null pointer when I tried retrieving data from database. I was inputting a data with a model and then retrieving it with same model but it throws null pointer exception saying a object is null even though it exists.

The problem is happening inside the model object instead of the activity file.

Here is the Diary Model where the problem occurs :

```
public class Diary implements Parcelable {
    @SerializedName("ID")
    @Expose
    private String ID;

    @SerializedName("ID Anak")
    @Expose
    private String IDAnak;

    @SerializedName("Nama Anak")
    @Expose
    private String NamaAnak;
    //Other Declarations
    .
    .
    .

    @SerializedName("Anak")
    @Expose
    private Anak Anak;
    //Other declarations
    .
    .
    .

    protected Diary(Parcel parcel){
        this.ID = parcel.readString();
        this.TanggalDiary = parcel.readString();
        this.IDAnak = parcel.readString();
        this.IDKamar = parcel.readString();
        this.NIA = parcel.readString();
        this.NamaAnak = parcel.readString();
        **this.Anak = parcel.readParcelable(Anak.getClass().getClassLoader()); //Here is where the problem is**
        this.NamaKamar = parcel.readString();
        this.IDAyah = parcel.readString();
        this.NamaAyah = parcel.readString();
        this.IDIbu = parcel.readString();
        this.NamaIbu = parcel.readString();
        this.Sarapan = parcel.readString();
        this.Susu = parcel.readString();
        this.SnackPagi = parcel.readString();
        this.MakanSiang = parcel.readString();
        this.TidurSiang = parcel.readString();
        this.SnackSore = parcel.readString();
        this.MakanSore = parcel.readString();
        this.BAB = parcel.readString();
        this.MinumObat = parcel.readString();
        this.Catatan = parcel.readString();
        this.Photo = parcel.readString();
        this.PhotoURL = parcel.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i){
        parcel.writeString(getID());
        parcel.writeString(getTanggalDiary());
        parcel.writeString(getIDAnak());
        parcel.writeString(getIDKamar());
        parcel.writeString(getNIA());
        parcel.writeString(getNamaAnak());
        parcel.writeParcelable(getAnak(), i);
        parcel.writeString(getNamaKamar());
        parcel.writeString(getIDAyah());
        parcel.writeString(getNamaAyah());
        parcel.writeString(getIDIbu());
        parcel.writeString(getNamaIbu());
        parcel.writeString(getSarapan());
        parcel.writeString(getSusu());
        parcel.writeString(getSnackPagi());
        parcel.writeString(getMakanSiang());
        parcel.writeString(getTidurSiang());
        parcel.writeString(getSnackSore());
        parcel.writeString(getMakanSore());
        parcel.writeString(getBAB());
        parcel.writeString(getMinumObat());
        parcel.writeString(getCatatan());
        parcel.writeString(getPhoto());
        parcel.writeString(getPhotoURL());
    }

    public Diary() {
    }

    public Diary(String ID,String TanggalDiary, String IDAnak, String IDKamar,String NIA, String NamaAnak, Anak Anak, String NamaKamar,String NamaKamarSearch,
                 String IDAyah, String NamaAyah, String NamaAyahSearch, String IDIbu, String NamaIbu, String NamaIbuSearch,
                 String Sarapan, String Susu, String SnackPagi, String MakanSiang, String TidurSiang, String SnackSore,
                 String MakanSore,String BAB, String MinumObat, String Catatan, String Photo, String PhotoURL, String CreatedBy, String CreatedIP, String CreatedPosition,
                 String CreatedDate, String ModifiedBy, String ModifiedIP, String ModifiedPosition, String ModifiedDate,
                   boolean IsActive) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.TanggalDiary = TanggalDiary;
        this.IDAnak = IDAnak;
        this.IDKamar = IDKamar;
        this.NIA = NIA;
        this.NamaAnak = NamaAnak;
        this.Anak = Anak;
        this.NamaKamar = NamaKamar;
        this.NamaKamarSearch = NamaKamarSearch;
        this.IDAyah = IDAyah;
        this.NamaAyah = NamaAyah;
        this.NamaAyahSearch = NamaAyahSearch;
        this.IDIbu = IDIbu;
        this.NamaIbu = NamaIbu;
        this.NamaIbuSearch = NamaIbuSearch;
        this.Sarapan = Sarapan;
        this.Susu = Susu;
        this.SnackPagi = SnackPagi;
        this.MakanSiang = MakanSiang;
        this.TidurSiang = TidurSiang;
        this.SnackSore = SnackSore;
        this.MakanSore = MakanSore;
        this.BAB = BAB;
        this.MinumObat = MinumObat;
        this.Catatan = Catatan;
        this.Photo = Photo;
        this.PhotoURL = PhotoURL;

        this.CreatedBy = CreatedBy;
        this.CreatedIP = CreatedIP;
        this.CreatedPosition = CreatedPosition;
        this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;

        this.ModifiedBy = ModifiedBy;
        this.ModifiedIP = ModifiedIP;
        this.ModifiedPosition = ModifiedPosition;
        this.ModifiedDate = ModifiedDate;

        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    
    public String getTanggalDiary() {return TanggalDiary; }
    
    public void setTanggalDiary(String tanggalDiary) { this.TanggalDiary = tanggalDiary; }

    public String getIDAnak() { return IDAnak; }

    public void setIDAnak(String idAnak) { this.IDAnak = idAnak; }

    public String getIDKamar() {return IDKamar; }

    public void setIDKamar(String idKamar) { this.IDKamar = idKamar; }

    public String getNIA() {return NIA;}

    public void setNIA(String nia) { this.NIA = nia; }

    public String getNamaAnak() {
        return NamaAnak;
    }

    public void setNamaAnak(String NamaAnak) {
        this.NamaAnak = NamaAnak;
    }

    public Anak getAnak() {return Anak;}

    public void  setAnak(Anak Anak) {this.Anak = Anak;}

    public String getNamaAnakSearch() { return  NamaAnakSearch; }

    public void setNamaAnakSearch(String NamaAnakSearch) { this.NamaAnakSearch = NamaAnakSearch; }

    public String getIDAyah() {return IDAyah;}

    public void setIDAyah(String IDAyah) {this.IDAyah = IDAyah; }

    public String getNamaAyah() {return NamaAyah;}

    public void setNamaAyah(String NamaAyah) {this.NamaAyah = NamaAyah;}

    public String getNamaAyahSearch() {return NamaAyahSearch;}

    public void setNamaAyahSearch(String NamaAyahSearch) {this.NamaAyahSearch = NamaAyahSearch;}

    public String getIDIbu() {return IDIbu; }

    public void setIDIbu(String IDIbu) {this.IDIbu = IDIbu;}

    public String getNamaIbu() {return NamaIbu = NamaIbu;}

    public void setNamaIbu(String NamaIbu) {this.NamaIbu = NamaIbu;}

    public String getNamaIbuSearch() {return NamaIbuSearch ;}

    public void setNamaIbuSearch(String NamaIbuSearch) {this.NamaIbuSearch = NamaIbuSearch;}

    public String getNamaKamar() {
        return NamaKamar;
    }

    public void setNamaKamar(String NamaKamar) {
        this.NamaKamar = NamaKamar;
    }

    public String getNamaKamarSearch() { return NamaKamarSearch; }

    public void setNamaKamarSearch(String NamaKamarSearch) { this.NamaKamarSearch = NamaKamarSearch; }

    public String getSarapan() {return Sarapan;}

    public void setSarapan(String Sarapan) { this.Sarapan = Sarapan; }

    public String getSusu() {return Susu;}

    public void setSusu(String Susu) {this.Susu = Susu;}

    public String getSnackPagi() { return SnackPagi; }

    public void setSnackPagi(String SnackPagi) { this.SnackPagi = SnackPagi; }

    public String getMakanSiang() { return MakanSiang; }

    public void setMakanSiang(String MakanSiang) { this.MakanSiang = MakanSiang; }

    public String getTidurSiang() { return TidurSiang; }

    public void setTidurSiang(String TidurSiang) {this.TidurSiang = TidurSiang;}

    public String getSnackSore() { return SnackSore; }

    public void setSnackSore(String snackSore) { this.SnackSore = snackSore; }

    public String getMakanSore() { return MakanSore; }

    public void setMakanSore(String MakanSore) { this.MakanSore = MakanSore; }

    public String getBAB() { return BAB; }

    public void setBAB(String bab) {this.BAB = bab; }

    public String getMinumObat() {return MinumObat;}

    public void setMinumObat(String MinumObat) {this.MinumObat = MinumObat; }

    public String getCatatan() { return Catatan; }

    public void setCatatan(String catatan) { this.Catatan = catatan;}

    public String getPhoto() {
        return Photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String Photo) {
        this.Photo = Photo;
    }

    public String getPhotoURL() {
        return PhotoURL;
    }

    public void setPhotoURL(String PhotoURL) {
        this.PhotoURL = PhotoURL;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return CreatedBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String CreatedBy) {
        this.CreatedBy = CreatedBy;
    }

    public String getCreatedIP() {
        return CreatedIP;
    }

    public void setCreatedIP(String CreatedIP) {
        this.CreatedIP = CreatedIP;
    }

    public String getCreatedPosition() {
        return CreatedPosition;
    }

    public void setCreatedPosition(String CreatedPosition) {
        this.CreatedPosition = CreatedPosition;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return CreatedDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String CreatedDate) {
        this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;
    }

    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return ModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String ModifiedBy) {
        this.ModifiedBy = ModifiedBy;
    }

    public String getModifiedIP() {
        return ModifiedIP;
    }

    public void setModifiedIP(String ModifiedIP) {
        this.ModifiedIP = ModifiedIP;
    }

    public String getModifiedPosition() {
        return ModifiedPosition;
    }

    public void setModifiedPosition(String ModifiedPosition) {
        this.ModifiedPosition = ModifiedPosition;
    }

    public String getModifiedDate() {
        return ModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(String ModifiedDate) {
        this.ModifiedDate = ModifiedDate;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return IsActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean IsActive) {
        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents(){ return  0;}

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Diary> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Diary>() {
        @Override
        public Diary createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) { return new Diary(parcel); }

        @Override
        public Diary[] newArray(int i) { return new Diary[i ]; }
    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.NamaAnak;            // What to display in the Spinner list.
    }
}
```

And here is the Logcat :

```
Throwable caught in onActivityCreated: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference: m.ki.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@233013037@23.30.13 (150400-0):44)
2023-08-09 06:44:15.606  5193-5193  AndroidRuntime          com.example.sekolahadmin             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sekolahadmin, PID: 5193
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sekolahadmin/com.example.sekolahadmin.Presentation.Diary.DetailDiaryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3770)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2202)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8096)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sekolahadmin.Model.Diary.<init>(Diary.java:161)
        at com.example.sekolahadmin.Model.Diary$1.createFromParcel(Diary.java:468)
        at com.example.sekolahadmin.Model.Diary$1.createFromParcel(Diary.java:466)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3284)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3177)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3575)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1001)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:8288)
        at com.example.sekolahadmin.Presentation.Diary.DetailDiaryActivity.initIntent(DetailDiaryActivity.java:89)
        at com.example.sekolahadmin.Presentation.Diary.DetailDiaryActivity.onCreate(DetailDiaryActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8142)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8114)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3571)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3770) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2202) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8096) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

This is my database looks like : [image: This is how my database looks like] My Database is Firebase

Should I include my Anak.java Model too?

I don't know what's the problem here, the object in question is there but Android thinks it is null

Please help enlightening me

At first I thought the problem is in Anak.java Model so I fixed it the object but it sill throws the same error, best I can do is to remove the Anak object from Diary and substitute it with different way but If possible I want to do it right with getParcelable

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.

It turns out I wrote wrong syntax for `readParcelable()` it should be `readParcelable(Anak.class.getClassLoader());` instead of `readParcelable(Anak.getClass().getClassLoader());`

so in essence it is (Your Class)**.class**.getClassLoader();

I hope this helps other who is getting this error thrown

Comment: If you had used lowercase on the `Anak` variable, and all others, as per conventions which have been generally accepted for 27 years, this issue could not have arisen.

Comment: The fact that you are a beginner is understandable, but (unfortunately) Stack Overflow could be very cruel with beginners. The SO is a repository of information about computer programming, so the questions must be relevant to anyone and dont specifcly to you. I know, self-learning is very hard, 'cause I do it too, but you said: *"internet is the only place I can ask around since my friends are not programmers"*, so you may need to network with other programmers and talk with them instead of simply asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The problem isn't asking, but **where** and **how** to do it, I make myself available to help if you want to! :)